# gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient while app is being "backgrounded"

Tags: objective-c, ios5, audio-recording, background-process

I have an (old) audio app that is misbehaving on iOS 5.1.1.  It records audio and on older iOS versions (don't know precisely where the "break" is) it would stay "in foreground" while recording, without any nudging.

But on 5.1.1 the app is put into background after two minutes, and then things go sour.  Currently (will have to change this, I suppose) the app kills recording when it's backgrounded (and it appears to do this successfully), but it still dies with a trap in the above routine.

Unfortunately, the call stack is empty when this occurs, so there's little clue as to *why* the app's getting killed, but I gather (just from hints here and there on the web) that the trap occurs because a background app cannot use any UI facilities, and the app must somehow be calling something UI-ish.  But I haven't a clue what it might be.

I've worked through most of the notifications, to see if a notification might be lurking in a queue somewhere and doing something, but I've not found anything so far that might be triggering a UI opp.

Any ideas on how to track this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!!  The app uses an Apple freebee widget known as AQLevelMeter.  When recording is stopped, the level meter is also stopped, but the stop code inside AQLevelMeter.mm does not invalidate the timer that's driving the UI updates.